# Issue with retaining the info of lasso select and box select in Plotly map with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, googlevis

I am trying to create an interactive map using Plotly in the Shiny app that allows the user to select the region by box select and lasso select on the map, then it can return a GoogleVis motion chart showing the statistics on the region selected within the Shiny app. Here is the UI function:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Johns Hopkins COVID-19 Modeling Visualization Map"),
    setBackgroundImage(
        src = "https://brand.jhu.edu/assets/uploads/sites/5/2014/06/university.logo_.small_.horizontal.blue_.jpg"
    ),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons("countyFill", "Choose the County Map Type", c("Map by total confirmed", "Map by total death"), selected = "Map by total confirmed"),
            checkboxGroupInput("statesInput", "Choose the State(s)", 
                               c("AL", "MO", "AK", "MT", "AZ", "NE", 
                                 "AR", "NV", "CA", "NH", "CO", "NJ", 
                                 "CT", "NM", "DE", "NY", "DC", "NC", 
                                 "FL", "ND", "GA", "OH", "HI", "OK", 
                                 "ID", "OR", "IL", "PA", "IN", "RI", 
                                 "IA", "SC", "KS", "SD", "KY", "TN", 
                                 "LA", "TX", "ME", "UT", "MD", "VT", 
                                 "MA", "VA", "MI", "WA", "MN", "WV", 
                                 "MS", "WI", "WY"),
                               inline = TRUE),                       
            submitButton("Submit (may take 30s to load)")
                ), 

        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                        tabPanel("County Level", plotlyOutput("countyPolygonMap"), htmlOutput("motionChart"), verbatimTextOutput("brush")), 
                        tabPanel("State Level", leafletOutput("statePolygonMap")),
            tags$div(
                tags$p(
                       "JHU.edu Copyright © 2020 by Johns Hopkins University & Medicine. All rights reserved."
                ),
                tags$p(
                    tags$a(href="https://it.johnshopkins.edu/policies/privacystatement",
                           "JHU Information Technology Privacy Statement for Websites and Mobile Applications")
                )
            )
            )
        )
)))
```

And here is the server function:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)
library(rgdal)
library(plotly)
library(rjson)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis) 
library(googleVis)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    statepolygonZip <- download.file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip", 
                                     destfile = "cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip");
    unzip("cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip");
    statePolygonData <- readOGR("cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp", layer = "cb_2018_us_state_500k", 
                                GDAL1_integer64_policy = TRUE);
    ## obtaning the state shape file data provided by cencus.gov 
    ## for more categories of region shape file: 
    ## https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html
    
    url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json'
    countyGeo <- rjson::fromJSON(file=url)
    ## Obtaining the geographical file for all U.S. counties
    
    url2<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv"
    covidCases <- read.csv(url2, header = TRUE)
    fips <- sprintf("%05d",covidCases$FIPS)
    colnames(covidCases)[6] <- "countyNames"
    totalComfirmed <- covidCases[,ncol(covidCases)]
    
    destroyX = function(es) {
        f = es
        for (col in c(1:ncol(f))){ #for each column in dataframe
            if (startsWith(colnames(f)[col], "X") == TRUE)  { #if starts with 'X' ..
                colnames(f)[col] <- substr(colnames(f)[col], 2, 100) #get rid of it
            }
        }
        assign(deparse(substitute(es)), f, inherits = TRUE) #assign corrected data to original name
    }
    destroyX(covidCases)

        gvisCasesData <- cbind.data.frame(covidCases$countyNames, covidCases[11,ncol(covidCases)])
        gvisCasesData <- melt(data = covidCases, id.vars = "countyNames",measure.vars = c(colnames(covidCases)[c(12:ncol(covidCases))]))
        colnames(gvisCasesData)[2:3] <- c("Date", "numCases")
        gvisCasesData$Date <- mdy(gvisCasesData$Date)
        
    
    url3 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv"
    covidDeath <- read.csv(url3, header = TRUE)
    totalDeath <- covidDeath[,ncol(covidDeath)]
    
    v <- reactiveValues(data = totalComfirmed)
    observeEvent(input$countyFill, {
        if (input$countyFill == "Map by total confirmed") {
           v$data <-  totalComfirmed;
           v$zmin = 100;
           v$zmax = 12000;
           v$hover <- with(covidCases, paste(countyName));
        }
        if (input$countyFill == "Map by total death") {
            v$data <-  totalDeath;
            v$zmin = 0;
            v$zmax = 1600;
            v$hover <- with(covidDeath, paste(countyName));
        }
    })
    
    output$countyPolygonMap <- renderPlotly({
        countyPolygonMap <- plot_ly(source = "countyMap") %>% add_trace(
            countyName <- covidCases$countyNames,
            type="choroplethmapbox",
            geojson=countyGeo,
            locations=fips,
            z=v$data,
            colorscale="Viridis",
            zmin= v$zmin,
            zmax= v$zmax,
            text = ~v$hover,
            marker=list(line=list(width=0),opacity=0.5)
        ) %>% layout(
            mapbox=list(
                style="carto-positron",
                zoom =2,
                center=list(lon= -95.71, lat=37.09))
        );
        countyPolygonMap;
        ## generating the interactive plotly map
    })
    
    output$motionChart <- renderGvis({
        subset(gvisCasesData, countyNames %in% c(selected))
        motionChart <- gvisMotionChart(gvisCasesDataSubset, "countyNames", "Date", options=list(width=800, height=400))
        plot(motionChart)
    })
   

    
    output$statePolygonMap <-renderLeaflet ({
        statesAbbr <- subset(statePolygonData, input$statesInput %in% statePolygonData$STUSPS);
        ## subsetting the shape file with the selected states
        
        leaflet(statesAbbr) %>%
            addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                        opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
                        fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", ALAND)(ALAND),
                        highlightOptions = highlightOptions
                        (color = "white", weight = 2,bringToFront = TRUE))
    })
    ## producing the map with polygon boundary on the state level
})
```

However, it always tries to jump to a web browser for the GoogleVis chart, and it gives the error of

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few issues. In your case, `actionButton` is better than `submitButton`. You need to have an `observeEvent` for this button in the server. When you `melt`, you need a data table. Lastly, `countyNames` was misspelled in one case. As I could not install googleVis, you should uncomment that part and run on your pc to get the `motionChart`. You should be able to fix the remaining part.
The following code gives the output at the bottom.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Johns Hopkins COVID-19 Modeling Visualization Map"),
  setBackgroundImage(
    src = "https://brand.jhu.edu/assets/uploads/sites/5/2014/06/university.logo_.small_.horizontal.blue_.jpg"
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("countyFill", "Choose the County Map Type", c("Map by total confirmed", "Map by total death"), selected = "Map by total confirmed"),
      checkboxGroupInput("statesInput", "Choose the State(s)", 
                         c("AL", "MO", "AK", "MT", "AZ", "NE", 
                           "AR", "NV", "CA", "NH", "CO", "NJ", 
                           "CT", "NM", "DE", "NY", "DC", "NC", 
                           "FL", "ND", "GA", "OH", "HI", "OK", 
                           "ID", "OR", "IL", "PA", "IN", "RI", 
                           "IA", "SC", "KS", "SD", "KY", "TN", 
                           "LA", "TX", "ME", "UT", "MD", "VT", 
                           "MA", "VA", "MI", "WA", "MN", "WV", 
                           "MS", "WI", "WY"),
                         inline = TRUE),                       
      actionButton("submit", "Submit (may take 30s to load)")
    ), 
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("County Level", plotlyOutput("countyPolygonMap"), 
                           #htmlOutput("motionChart"), 
                           verbatimTextOutput("brush")), 
                  tabPanel("State Level", leafletOutput("statePolygonMap")),
                  tags$div(
                    tags$p(
                      "JHU.edu Copyright © 2020 by Johns Hopkins University & Medicine. All rights reserved."
                    ),
                    tags$p(
                      tags$a(href="https://it.johnshopkins.edu/policies/privacystatement",
                             "JHU Information Technology Privacy Statement for Websites and Mobile Applications")
                    )
                  )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  statepolygonZip <- download.file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip", 
                                   destfile = "cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip");
  unzip("cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip");
  statePolygonData <- readOGR("cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp", layer = "cb_2018_us_state_500k", 
                              GDAL1_integer64_policy = TRUE);
  ## obtaning the state shape file data provided by cencus.gov 
  ## for more categories of region shape file: 
  ## https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html
  
  url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json'
  countyGeo <- rjson::fromJSON(file=url)
  ## Obtaining the geographical file for all U.S. counties
  
  url2<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv"
  covidCases <- read.csv(url2, header = TRUE)
  fips <- sprintf("%05d",covidCases$FIPS)
  colnames(covidCases)[6] <- "countyNames"
  totalComfirmed <- covidCases[,ncol(covidCases)]
  
  destroyX = function(es) {
    f = es
    for (col in c(1:ncol(f))){ #for each column in dataframe
      if (startsWith(colnames(f)[col], "X") == TRUE)  { #if starts with 'X' ..
        colnames(f)[col] <- substr(colnames(f)[col], 2, 100) #get rid of it
      }
    }
    assign(deparse(substitute(es)), f, inherits = TRUE) #assign corrected data to original name
  }
  destroyX(covidCases)
  
  gvisCasesData <- cbind.data.frame(covidCases$countyNames, covidCases[11,ncol(covidCases)])
  gvisCasesData <- melt(data = setDT(covidCases), id.vars = "countyNames",measure.vars = c(colnames(covidCases)[c(12:ncol(covidCases))]))
  colnames(gvisCasesData)[2:3] <- c("Date", "numCases")
  gvisCasesData$Date <- mdy(gvisCasesData$Date)
  
  
  url3 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv"
  covidDeath <- read.csv(url3, header = TRUE)
  totalDeath <- covidDeath[,ncol(covidDeath)]
  
  v <- reactiveValues(data = totalComfirmed)
  observeEvent(input$countyFill, {
    if (input$countyFill == "Map by total confirmed") {
      v$data <-  totalComfirmed;
      v$zmin = 100;
      v$zmax = 12000;
      v$hover <- with(covidCases, paste(countyNames));
    }
    if (input$countyFill == "Map by total death") {
      v$data <-  totalDeath;
      v$zmin = 0;
      v$zmax = 1600;
      v$hover <- with(covidDeath, paste(countyNames));
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    req(input$submit)
    
    output$countyPolygonMap <- renderPlotly({
      countyPolygonMap <- plot_ly(source = "countyMap") %>% add_trace(
        countyName <- covidCases$countyNames,
        type="choroplethmapbox",
        geojson=countyGeo,
        locations=fips,
        z=v$data,
        colorscale="Viridis",
        zmin= v$zmin,
        zmax= v$zmax,
        text = ~v$hover,
        marker=list(line=list(width=0),opacity=0.5)
      ) %>% layout(
        mapbox=list(
          style="carto-positron",
          zoom =2,
          center=list(lon= -95.71, lat=37.09))
      );
      countyPolygonMap;
      ## generating the interactive plotly map
    })
    
    # output$motionChart <- renderGvis({
    #   subset(gvisCasesData, countyNames %in% c(selected))
    #   motionChart <- gvisMotionChart(gvisCasesDataSubset, "countyNames", "Date", options=list(width=800, height=400))
    #   plot(motionChart)
    # })
    
    output$statePolygonMap <-renderLeaflet ({
      statesAbbr <- subset(statePolygonData,  statePolygonData$STUSPS %in% input$statesInput);
      ## subsetting the shape file with the selected states
      
      leaflet(statesAbbr) %>%
        addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                    opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
                    fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", ALAND)(ALAND),
                    highlightOptions = highlightOptions
                    (color = "white", weight = 2,bringToFront = TRUE))
    })
    ## producing the map with polygon boundary on the state level
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but the googleVis motion chart wasn't generated when I uncommented the part. I am thinking that this might have something to do with event_register() and event_data()

Comment: I cannot install googleVis at the moment. So I cannot verify that part.  Also, you needed to update state level, as it was giving random states in your previous setup. But now it looks fine.  Your call had  `allstates %in% input`, whereas it should be `input %in% allstates`.